# Set max and min values of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix 640-by-480 where each element has data. I want to set the values of the element to zero where the original values are not between two numbers. For example, `A` is a 640-by-480 matrix. For the `i`-th element `A(i)`, if the value of `A(i)` is between `10` and `20` leave it, if not then set `A(i)=0`. Could anyone suggest a simple way instead of using loops?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this for values between 10 and 20:

```
A(A < 10 | A > 20) = 0;
```

The expression "A < 10 | A > 20" creates a logical mask, then the values under this mask are set to zeros.